# Is there an in-universe reason that Inklings evolved to be human-like?

Tags: splatoon

In *Splatoon*, Inklings, who evolved from squids to replace humans as the dominant species after rising sea levels caused them to go extinct, look like stylized humans other than their eyes and hair in their main form:

[image: a very humanoid Inkling]

**Is there an in-universe explanation as to how Inklings became so similar to humans?**

<sub>note to reflexive annoying commenters and close voters: this game is very much science fiction. [Sci-fi video games are on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/320/102999).</sub>

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GoalOrientedEvolution

Comment: @Valorum I’m expecting that is probably the answer. There’s a surprising amount of lore stuff that might answer it, though.

Comment: If you want the out-of-universe explanation, it's because they originally had rabbits in the game, then replaced them with squids. They wanted to keep the ears (and the overall humanoid form) because they help an overhead viewer determine the character's direction and a humanoid form is easier to animate and see (and presumably to market); https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Iwata-Asks/Iwata-Asks-Splatoon/Splatoon/2-Then-Rabbits/2-Then-Rabbits-1021367.html

Comment: [The Splatoon Origins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIRprkVSwFo)

Comment: @Valorum - ... and before the rabbits, the primary characters were *' black and white blocks of tofu with noses that sprayed ink.'*. [source](https://splatoon.fandom.com/wiki/Splatoon)

Comment: @Jeeped - Astoundingly, audiences didn't warm to the idea of playing animated rectangles.

Comment: They're only similar to humans half the time. *'Inklings can alternate between humanoid and squid form ...'* [source](https://splatoon.fandom.com/wiki/Inklings) (but you probably already knew that)

Comment: @Jeeped I specified “in their main form” in the question.

Comment: Your question might be better as *'Is there an in-universe explanation for how and why the Inklings developed the ability to morph between their original squid form and a bipedal adaptation?'*